# Forgot my mail id & password of my google account , how recover id & password?

Tags: google-account

IForgot my mail id & password of my google account , how recover id & password ?
my phone was rebooted and it cant start without google account & not accept any other google account pls help me

Answer (score 0):

If you have used your mobile number while creating your account then that will useful for recover your account.

Follow these steps to recover your email id.

Step 1: Go to the gmail.com

Step 2: Click on Forgot email?

Step 3: Now add your mobile number.

Step 4: Add your first name and last name you used while creating your account.

Step 5: Now google will send one verification code to your mobile number.

Step 6: Just add that code into the textfield and press submit.

Step 7: Now google will display all the account that associated with your mobile number.

Now check your account email is exist or not.

Comment: Please add the source of this information.